# Pandas: Merging 2 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataset like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([["2013-01-01", 4, 1000, 1],
              ["2013-01-02", 8, 500, 1],
              ["2013-01-03", 4, 1000, -1],
              ["2013-01-04", 4, 1000, 1],
              ["2013-01-05", 3, 300, 1]], 
             columns=["date", "shop_id", "item_id", "item_count"])
```

[image]

We have the `item_count` variable which is either positive or negative. **Being positive means the item was sold** and **being negative means the item was returned**.

What I would like to do is to remove the rows where the **same item** was returned. For instance in the dataframe above row with id 0 and 2 will cancel each other out but row with id 3 will remain. How can I achieve this? I though about few solutions but they involve using `.apply()` and are not very efficient for large datasets. Thanks

Comment: I didn't really understand the logic here. You said client 1 and 4 will cancel out since they returned same item, but for both client 1 and 4, the item_counts is +1 (means the item was sold).

Comment: If you want to remove the row , at list they should share the same client_id

Comment: @YilunZhang My bad I edited the post, client 1 and 3 will cancel each other out, client 4 will remain.

Comment: @Wen I edited the post, it should be less confusing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since return Item always come with the ordered item, you can using `shift` up to local the item which has been returned

```
df[(df.groupby('shop_id').item_count.shift(-1).fillna(1).ne(-1))&(df.item_count.ne(-1))]
Out[247]: 
         date  shop_id  item_id  item_count
1  2013-01-02        8      500           1
3  2013-01-04        4     1000           1
4  2013-01-05        3      300           1
```

Update :

```
df.groupby(['shop_id','item_id']).agg({'item_count':'sum','date':'last'})
Out[249]: 
                       date  item_count
shop_id item_id                        
3       300      2013-01-05           1
4       1000     2013-01-04           1
8       500      2013-01-02           1
```

Comment: That's a solution but not quite what I'm looking for. In the toy problem I presented the items are indeed ordered but in my real dataset they can not be. Plus you are using `.ne(-1)` but the value could be less than -1, like -2 or -3

Comment: I mean, considering the item was sold at least 2 times ofc. What I meant is hardcoding -1 isn't really a solution considering the quantities should be subtracted from each other (the sold quantity minus the returned one)